# How to draw single line diagram in odoo?

Tags: xml, odoo

How to draw single line diagram in odoo any pakages do we have for odoo,any module, I have requiement like if i click on any point of image then it should get info of that asset.like SVG

Comment: your meaning is that web diagram of any class and module?

Comment: yeah something like that only

Answer (score 0):

There is One Module available  for Web Diagram in ODOO App Store

https://apps.openerp.com/apps/modules/9.0/web_diagram/

This module is for Different Different Odoo Version 9.0 , 8.0 , 7.0 , 6.1 and master.
So you can download it customize it and this module is Free on Odoo App Store.

may be this is Helping You.